# Handling special characters like $'\346' on bash

Tags: bash, non-ascii-characters

I have a number of files with characters such as `$'\351'` and `$'\346'`. I haven't figured out how to reference these files on bash. How can I use `mv` and `sed` to change their names?

When I run `ls`, one of the files that appears, for example, is shown as:

```
'根'$'\346''%8B'$'\240''.html'
```

Comment: These are files with those characters in the name? Can you post an example filename?

Comment: @MikeGorski : added an example

Comment: What is this filename supposed to be?

Comment: @thatotherguy : if you mean what I'd like to rename it to be, I suppose I might want to rename it to `根_346%8B_240.html`

Comment: Do you use a very recent `ls` that quotes its output?

Comment: @BenjaminW. : `ls (GNU coreutils) 8.28` ... I'm not sure if it's quoting output or not. It doesn't quote output for most files.

Comment: The quoting was introduced in 8.25, https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8445

Comment: @JellicleCat So you don't care about restoring it to the name that was originally intended, you just want to rename it to something else that's merely unique and valid utf-8?

Comment: @thatotherguy : correct

Comment: Pretty sure `mv '根'$'\346''%8B'$'\240''.html' newname.html` should work then.

Comment: @BenjaminW. : thanks. (*’ヮ’*)

Comment: If you don't care about the original name, why don't you just rename them all to `1.html`, `2.html`, etc

Comment: @thatotherguy : that would be okay; but as a rule, I like to avoid irreversible transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most users in this situation would want to use `convmv` to convert the encoding of such filenames.

However, since you don't really know or care what the original filename was supposed to be but just want a reversible transformation to make the names easier to deal with, you could rename all files to a hexdump of their bytes:

```
export LC_ALL=C
for f in *
do
  mv -- "$f" "$(printf '%s' "$f" | od -t x1 -An | tr -cd 'a-f0-9')"
done
```

This will e.g. turn the file `'根'$'\346''%8B'$'\240''.html'` into `e6a0b9e6253842a02e68746d6c`

Comment: Do you understand how the filenames could be created in the first place? When I try to `touch` the example filename, I get an "Illegal byte sequence" error. Were they created in a non-UTF8 locale?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Are you on Mac or Windows? HFS+ and NTFS use character based filenames rather than byte based filenames, so they're unable to store files with invalid encoding.

Comment: Oh, that's it. On macOS, I can't create them, in a Bash docker container running Alpine Linux, I can.